# azure search Indexer is stopped with errors

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to index bulk data stored in Azure blob storage. The storage consists different types of data with different sizes. Indexer was stopped with errors. I don't want indexer to be stopped even when there are any errors also.

**`Error: Could not extract content or metadata from document`**

Trying to index bulk data from search index and indexer is failing with below error,
**`Error: Could not extract content or metadata from document`**

Comment: what is the type of the doc which raised the error?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the indexer you can specify the `MaxFailedItems` and `MaxFailedItemsPerBatch`. By setting these to `-1` you can indicate that it should continue even if any errors are present.

In case you created the indexer using the C# SDK you can add those parameters like this:

```cs
var indexer = new SearchIndexer(indexerName, dataSourceName, indexName)
{
    //... other settings
    Parameters = new IndexingParameters()
    {
        MaxFailedItems = -1,
        MaxFailedItemsPerBatch = -1,
    },
};
```

In case you are using the Azure Portal you can find them in the UI under the settings tab when you are creating the indexer. You can also update an existing indexer from either the Portal or using code.