# Index for azure search getting error for bulk data

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

While I am trying to index large amounts of data from the search index, the indexer encounters the following error -

**Error :- Could not extract content or metadata from document.**

```
var indexer = new SearchIndexer(indexerName, dataSourceName, indexName)
{
    //... other settings
    Parameters = new IndexingParameters()
    {
        MaxFailedItems = -1,
        MaxFailedItemsPerBatch = -1,
    },
};
```

I don't want the indexer to be halted at all times,including when there are errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure in indexer as shown below, If you don't want to stop indexer execution even if there are errors or unprocessed documents.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://xxxx.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"sddsdf\"",
  "name": "azureblob-indexer",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "ds01",
  "skillsetName": "azureblob-skillset",
  "targetIndexName": "azureblob-index",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 100,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 100,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/people",
      "targetFieldName": "people"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/organizations",
      "targetFieldName": "organizations"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/locations",
      "targetFieldName": "locations"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/keyphrases",
      "targetFieldName": "keyphrases"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/language",
      "targetFieldName": "language"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/translated_text",
      "targetFieldName": "translated_text"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/pii_entities",
      "targetFieldName": "pii_entities"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/masked_text",
      "targetFieldName": "masked_text"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content",
      "targetFieldName": "merged_content"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/text",
      "targetFieldName": "text"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/layoutText",
      "targetFieldName": "layoutText"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/imageTags/*/name",
      "targetFieldName": "imageTags"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/imageCaption",
      "targetFieldName": "imageCaption"
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

[image]

maxFailedItems and maxFailedItemsPerBatch are used to ignore errors.

Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-common-errors-warnings) for more details

- Also Verify that the indexer has the appropriate access rights to the data source and that it can access and extract data from the documents.
- You can also refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75232601/azure-search-indexer-is-stopped-with-errors) question it may helps.